# Programmatically change 'is_active' of category in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

How can I programmatically change the value of 'is_active' in Magento 2? What I have tried so far (in an observer) is:

```
class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{   
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_repository;

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $repository
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_repository = $repository;
    }

    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $categoryCollection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('eq' => 'test'));
        $currentCategory = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem();

        $currentCategory->setIsActive(true);
        $this->_repository->save($currentCategory);
    }
}
```

The 'is_active' value is not changing. It seems that the only values that can be changed with the magical set functions are the values of the table catalog_category_entity.

Comment: You don't need to load collection In which event you are using for this

Comment: It is the event `admin_system_config_changed_%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**is_active** is managed at store Level

make sure you change store id to `0` for admin level , the value you have saved to store level , you can confirm by changing **Store View** drop down in admin page for category edit.

try following to save in admin level

```
 public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $categoryCollection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $categoryCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('eq' => 'test'));
        $currentCategory = $categoryCollection->getFirstItem();
        $currentCategory->setStoreId(0);
        $currentCategory->setIsActive(true);
        $this->_repository->save($currentCategory);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! It seems to be important to set the store id before setting is_active.

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 set category value is active by script It's run from root directory

Create file.php copy and passt below code and import in root after run like (DomainName/file.php)

```
<?php
//increase the max execution time
@ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
//memory_limit
@ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');

$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

$categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

$categories = $categoryCollection->create();

$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$categories->load();

if (count($categories) > 0):

        foreach($categories as $category):

            $catId = $category->getId();

                $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->setStoreId(0)->load($catId);
                $CategoryName = $category->getName();

                $category->setIsActive(1);
                $category->save();

        endforeach;
     else: echo "No Results";
    endif;

?>
```